# How to get string length in function

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, strlen

How can I get the length of the buffer in the function using pointers?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fun(char *(buffer))
{
    printf(strlen(buffer));
}

int main()
{
    char buffer[] = "Hello";
    fun(&buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: The string `buffer` is already a pointer, so `&` is not necessary in this example.

Comment: Save time.  Enable all warnings to see trouble with `printf(strlen(buffer));`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the header

```
#include <string.h>
```

then in the function to write

```
void fun(char *buffer)
{
    printf( "%zu\n", strlen( buffer ) );
}
```

or

```
void fun(char *buffer)
{
    size_t n = strlen( buffer );
    printf( "%zu\n", n );
}
```

and at last to call the function like

```
fun( buffer );
```

If you need to get the length of the passed string within the function yourself without using the standard string function `strlen` then the function can look like

```
void fun(char *buffer)
{
    const char *p = buffer;

    while ( *p ) ++p;
    size_t n = p - buffer;

    printf( "%zu\n", n );
}
```